# Scrolling using marquee tag

Tags: html, css, marquee

I facing problem using marquee tag, when opening in the chrome browser looks perfectly but when we open in firefox there are totally black shows.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use `<marquee>`

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element)

> The marquee tag is a non-standard HTML element which causes text to
>   scroll up, down, left or right automatically. The tag was first
>   introduced in early versions of Microsoft's Internet Explorer, and was
>   compared to Netscape's blink element, as a proprietary non-standard
>   extension to the HTML standard with usability problems. It is
>   deprecated by the W3C and not advised by them for use in any HTML
>   documents.

if you still want marquee to work as expected see this
http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

Comment: so what exactly i want to do ?
i need auto scrolling slideshow logo.

Comment: i want to set up client logo images with marquee but its set with vertically form

Answer (score 2):

Using just CSS, as your tags say, a solution would be to use [**keyframe animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/animation). However, **keyframe animations are not supported in IE9 or older** (IE10 supports them and so do all current versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera).

Example using keyframe animations: http://dabblet.com/gist/3155878

HTML

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <ul class="logo-list">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="logo-img1.jpg"></a>
        </li><li><a href="#"><img src="logo-img2.jpg"></a>
        </li><!--many more list items just like this-->
        </ul>
</div>
```

Basic CSS

```
.carousel-wrapper {
    width: 32em;
    height: 9em;
    margin: 10em auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.logo-list {
    margin: 0 0 0 16em;
    padding: .5em 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: scrollme 35s infinite linear alternate;
}
.logo-list li {
    padding: .25em;
    display: inline-block;
}
.logo-list a {
    width: 10em;
    height: 7.5em;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    display: block;
}
@keyframes scrollme {
    to {margin-left: -173em;}
    /* 173em = 18 list items * 10.5em - 16em
    (10.5em = 10em width + 2*.25em paddings left and right)
    (16em = half the width of the wrapper) */
}
```

---

---

**Solutions for IE9 and older**:

**1.** Use JavaScript. With jQuery, it's as easy as:

```
$('.logo-list').animate({ marginLeft: '-173em'}, 35000, 'linear');​
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/gTRXQ/1/

However, *if JavaScript is disabled, the user will only see the first images* (unless he selects and drags... which most users don't).

---

**2.** Just CSS. Well, the exact same effect (auto-scrolling) cannot be achieved, but there are a few options.

Fist of all, add `.lt-ie9` and `.ie9` classes on the `<html>` element:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><html class="lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

so that you could do something different.

**a)** First option: the ugly option. No auto-scrolling, just leave a horizontal scrollbar on the wrapper (and of course increase its height) so that the user can scoll to see all images.

```
.ie9 .carousel-wrapper, .lt-ie9 .carousel-wrapper {
    height: 10em;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

**b)** Second option: works only when there aren't that many images. Stack them up and reveal them on `hover` - something like I did in this gallery: http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/F7MKy/6/

**c)** Option that will only work in IE9, but you could use option a) or b) as fallback for older versions. Add some kind of navigation, like this http://dabblet.com/gist/3156683 (view it in IE9).

**d)** Ugly option #2. Go back to marquee just for IE9 and older (using conditional comments).

---

What I would do:

To begin with, add a class `.no-js` to the `<html>`

Use [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/) to remove it if JavaScript is not disabled. In this case, use the JavaScript version of the auto-scrolling.

If JavaScript is disabled, but animations are supported, use keyframe animations. In this case, the `.no-js` class was not removed, so:

```
.no-js .logo-list { animation: scrollme 35s infinite linear alternate; }
```

If neither JavaScript nor animations are supported, try another one of the options I've listed at point **2**.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct the structural errors in your site.

For instance, the marquee is inside an `<ul>` element, but outside of any `<li>` elements. I'm sure browsers will have a problem with this!
So make sure the site validates on http://validator.w3.org/ before continuing.